# jQuery - Display a textbox when a link/button is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, textarea

I'm trying to put a reply button for each comment so when someone click on the button (for example "Reply"), a textbox will come up automatically where users can fill in a form.

I didn't do much so far...

### PHP

```
<div id='replycomment' class='reply' onclick='jsReply($comment_id);'>Reply</div>
<div id='showreply'></div>
```

### jQuery

```
function jsReply(comment_id) {
    var form = '<form id="showReplyForm" action"add_reply.php" method="post">';
    form += '<textarea name="replybody" cols="35" rows="2" maxlength="299"</textarea>';
    form += '<input type="hidden" name="replybodyId" value="' + comment_id + '" />'
    form += '<input type="submit" name="replysubmit" value="Reply"/></form>';
    jQuery('#replybody').replaceWith(form); }
```

Can anyone PLEASE help me with that? it would be much appreciated.
I'm a bit confused with the way I need to link the id from jquery to php...

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To make your code work, do this: http://jsfiddle.net/MaqLQ/1/

within head:

```
var jsReply = function(comment_id) {
    var form = '<form id="showReplyForm" action"add_reply.php" method="post">';
    form += '<textarea name="replybody" cols="35" rows="2" maxlength="299"></textarea>';
    form += '<input type="hidden" name="replybodyId" value="' + comment_id + '" />';
    form += '<input type="submit" name="replysubmit" value="Reply"/></form>';
    jQuery('#showreply').replaceWith(form);
}
```

you were missing a semi-colin at the end of one of your form concatenations. you were looking at 'replyBody' rather than the 'showreply' that exists in your html, and **if** your code wasn't global your html it wouldn't have been defined for the onclick. you were also missing the end angle bracket for your opening textarea tag.

also, i don't know your context and i'm not here for a code review, but among a few other things... you should really avoid using `onclick` within your html elements.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the jQuery library.

Hide `#showreply` via CSS `display: none;` and place the HTML form within it.

```
$('#replycomment').click(function() {
    $('#showreply').show();
});
```

I also recommend changing your IDs to classes since you will have multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

```
<div class='reply'>Reply</div>
<form action='add_reply.php' method='POST' class='reply-form'>
  <textarea name='replybody'></textarea>
  <input type='hidden' name='comment_id' value='<?php echo $comment_id; ?>' />
  <input type='submit' value='Reply' />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.reply-form {
  display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".reply").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".reply-form").show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```